# Any collection of neighborhoods of a dense set cover the space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Trying to solve an exercise, I'm trying to see if this is true:

> Let $X$ a Hausdorff space and $D\subset X$ dense. Also let a function $$f:D\to\wp(X),\quad x\mapsto U_x$$ where $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Then we can say that $X=\bigcup f(D)$?

I'm unable to prove it so probably it's false. My first idea was taking each $U_x$ open, then $U:=\bigcup f(D)$ is also open and $U^\complement$ closed. Then if my assertion would be true, it must be the case that $U^\complement=\emptyset$, but I'm unable to show this.

Can someone confirm if there exists some Hausdorff space where my hypothesis doesn't work? Or, by the contrary, if my hypothesis is true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is false even in the real line. Let $\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ be an ennumeration of the rationals and consider the neighborhoods $(r_n-\frac 1 {2^{n}},r_n+\frac 1 {2^{n}})$. Since the total length of these intervals is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{n-1}}=2$, they cannot cover the entire line. [ If you know measure theory you can see the reason immediately. Otherwise you can see that the intervals don't even cover $[0,3]$ using a compactness argument.]

Answer (score 9):

If $y\notin D$ then you can choose for $U_x=X-\{y\}$ for every $x\in D$ - which is evidently an open neighborhood of $x$ in Hausdorff space $X$.

Then the union of these sets is again $X-\{y\}\neq X$.

Apparantly that statement is false already if $X$ is a $T_1$-space.